# Exclude moc files from solution generated by Cmake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake, moc

I create a project with cmake for Visual Studio 10, using Qt5.4 library. Cmake generates moc files for Qt and integrates these files into my solution.

I would like to find a way to prevent Cmake to integrate the moc files into the solution, coz then they are compiled what is useless I think.

Does it exist a solution to do that ?

I am not writing something like set(moc_mymocfile.cpp) into the CMakeLists.txt file, so I don't understand...

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "solution"? I don't think you can compile QObjects without the corresponding moc files. They are needed for example when you use signal/slots.

Comment: Yes actually, you are probably right and I was totally wrong. I mean the Visual Studio Solution. But is it possible to hide them into the solution ? They are all in the same location than my "real" source files, and considering I never open them, I would like to "hide" them in Visual Studio...

Comment: If this is about Visual Studio details, I am out. But usually you have a different source and build directory. When used with qmake, the moc files are in the build directory together with all the compiled objects where they are not disturbing.

Comment: I think it's exactly what I want to have : sources & moc files in separated filters inside VS. And considering that Cmake is responsible of the creation of solution (VS project), I hope there exist a special command or option, but I don't find it
Thanks for your time

Comment: Which version of cmake do you use? Writing moc files to the build directory should be the default: *Generated moc_*.cpp and *.moc files are placed in the build directory* http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#automoc

Comment: qmake does what you want.

Comment: I am using the 3.2.0 rc2 version. I'm ok with the fact that moc files are generated, placed in the build directory and then compiled, but I am looking for a way to hide them in my visual studio solution, because I have a lot of moc files and I'd like not seeing them

Comment: 7 years after, still same problem for me ? did you figure out how to fix that ?